# this keyword on this.appendChild (articleItemElement); refer to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, custom-element, this

In short I have a javascript file that contains an array of data in which there are 4 objects, each object consisting of 4 properties, and then the second file is...

==========================================

```
(article-item.js)

class ArticleItem extends HTMLElement {
 set article(article) {
   this._article = article;
   this.render();
 }

     render() {
       this.innerHTML = `
    <img class="featured-image" src="${this._article.featuredImage}">
    <div class="article-info">
        <h2><a href="${this._article.id}">${this._article.title}</a></h2>
        <p>${this._article.description}</p>
    </div>

  `;
 }
}
 
customElements.define("article-item", ArticleItem);
```

=====================================================

```
(article-list.js)

import "./article-item.js"
 
 
class ArticleList extends HTMLElement {
 set articles(articles) {
   this._articles = articles;
   this.render();
 }
 
 
 render() {
   this._articles.forEach(article => {
     const articleItemElement = document.createElement("article-item");
     // memanggil fungsi setter article() pada article-item.
     articleItemElement.article = article;
     this.appendChild(articleItemElement);
   })
 }
}
 
customElements.define("article-list", ArticleList);
```

============================================================

Today I am learning about Nested Custom Elements, I quite understand how the program flow runs. But there are some parts that I still don't understand, like what this line / keyword this does in (this.appendChild (articleItemElement);), then in (articleItemElement.article = article;) I understand that I can only assign data to custom elements via JavaScript syntax by accessing the .article property if using the accessor property or the getter / setter technique. What is the function of part (= article)? or if I'm wrong please explain the function of the line

I really hope and thank if someone would explain that for me

Comment: `this` here refers to the `article-list` element that you are operating on. `article` is the iteration variable of the `this._articles` array call to `.forEach`. These are unrelated concepts. I suggest you read up on `forEach` and higher order functions first and foremost.

Comment: If you don't understand code always add plenty of ``console.log( article )`` statements.